# How can I install a driver for an Intel 82573 Gigabit ethernet card?

Tags: installation, drivers, ethernet

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my computer, The only problem so far is there is no Internet connection. I believe that's due to missing drivers which are difficult to install without Internet. So I am hoping some one can help me find the drivers I need and give me some tips on installing the drivers.

The Motherboard is an `Intel® D975XBX2` and the **Ethernet** is a `Intel® 82573E/82573L Gigabit Ethernet Controller`

I tried installing the Linux drivers [from here](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Ethernet%20Components&ProductLine=Ethernet%20Controllers&ProductProduct=Intel%C2%AE%2082573L%20Gigabit%20Ethernet%20Controller).
Except when I tried to run `rpmbuild`, like I was told to do in the *readme* it said it wasn't installed.

Answer (score 1):

This guide is a little old, but your card may be a mess made by Intel and never fixed:
http://thesorcerer.wordpress.com/2011/07/01/guide-intel-82573l-gigabit-ethernet-with-ubuntu-11-04-and-fix-pxe-e05/

Comment: THANK YOU! I am thanking you using the machine so thanks!:)